# How to conveniently convert this string as a list?

Tags: python

```
s = '[a,b,c]'
```

This is a string, how can I easily convert it to a list into python? I guess there is an easy way to do it, but my way is ugly.

```
s = s[1:-1]
s = s.split(',')
```

Comment: `s[1:-1].split(",")`

Comment: I think what you have is fine.  I don't think there's any "easier" way.  The only problem with your method that I see is that it requires a fairly specific input format.  If that's reliable, then what you're doing seems pretty good to me

Answer (score 3):

You can also try :

```
s.strip('[]').split(',')
```

Comment: This does more work than the OPs version, as it doesn't take into account the knowledge that '[' is at the beginning and ']' is at the end of the input nor that you'll be taking exactly one character off of the front and back.

Comment: Thanks @CryptoFool. That was very insightful. I learned something today.

Answer (score 1):

If the string format is not reliable you can use `re.sub` to remove all whitespaces and `[`, `]`

```py
import re
s = "   [    a,   c,    x,    d,             e       ]   "
l = re.sub(r'[\s\[\]]', '', s).split(',')
```

Comment: Should you be using `\s` instead of a space in the regex?

Comment: @RoyCohen I think both will work in this case. `\s` matches any whitespace and a space will only match ASCII 32 character. But using `\s` will be better I think so updated my answer :)